# Android Bluetooth Socket

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

What I am trying to do:
I am working on an application that will fetch data from biometric device using Bluetooth using SPP. For that I have some command (in byte and HEX format) and steps provided by biometric device manufacturer.

My Problem :
I have to follow 2 steps for getting the data i.e. send two commands one after another. The biometric device return data when receive second command. I have successfully establish connection with device and execute first command but when I send second command to device the app get stuck and after some time biometric device terminate connection and I receive IO Exception : Socket closed, don't understand what is happening on second command.

I have done:
I have used BluetoothChatService.class from [Bluetooth Chat](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) example provided in Android SDK Samples and modify [ConnectThread](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) thread's Run function according to my requirement i.e. I am sending commands in this function. And used "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" UUID. For connecting to socket I have tried following codes :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            }
            else {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            }
```

And

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", 
                    new Class[] { int.class });
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

And

```
tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

Any one know where I am wrong?

Thank you in advance. 
but one of these can solve my problem.

**Edit**
I have resolve this problem. Here is method who I am establishing socket connection

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 10){
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

}

> else{
>       tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
>   }

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the biometric device is requesting for Security ? 
And it could be disconnecting if Bluetooth Security procedure is not being performed. 
Few Questions :
Which Android version are you using ? 
Do you know the SPP connection requirements (security requirements) of the device ?
Also share the Bluetooth logcat traces to confirm the issue

Comment: I have check documents provided and it don't specify and security requirements. I am testing this on HTC desire, HTC desire HD, and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1.